# Android to Arduino Mega ADK board REconnecting

Tags: adk

When I connect my Arduino Mega ADK board to an AOA Android app everything is fine (initially), the connection to the ADK board is fully functional in both directions.  However, if the screen rotates, someone hits back, the screen locks, etc, when the app restarts the openAccessory call to the USB manager always returns null.  So students have to unplug the USB before the connection can be made again.

I've figured out the problem is related to the Input Stream, because if I don't start the Thread to receive commands then there is no issue.  However that's not really a useful fix. :)

My code is here:
https://github.com/ME435/AndroidLibraries_v01/blob/master/src/edu/rosehulman/me435/AccessoryActivity.java

I just subclass my AccessoryActivity in apps like this...

https://github.com/ME435/LED-Toggle/blob/master/src/edu/rosehulman/ledtoggle/LedToggleActivity.java

It's not robust, but it's very simple for students.  Thoughts on my issue?